# Installing spaCy package on Mac: error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I want to install spaCy on my system but the terminal is showing a gcc error as I try the following:

> > pip install -U spacy

The error says:

```
Running setup.py install for spacy ... error
Complete output from command /Users/ellie/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/4v/k_fzzx3j68sd2fqcnx7m8yxc0000gn/T/pip-install-u5e_udi_/spacy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/4v/k_fzzx3j68sd2fqcnx7m8yxc0000gn/T/pip-record-mlz5dts_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'spacy.parts_of_speech' extension
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/ellie/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/ellie/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/ellie/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -I/private/var/folders/4v/k_fzzx3j68sd2fqcnx7m8yxc0000gn/T/pip-install-u5e_udi_/spacy/include -I/Users/ellie/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c spacy/parts_of_speech.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/spacy/parts_of_speech.o -O2 -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-unused-function
gcc: error: spacy/parts_of_speech.cpp: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I appreciate any recommendations.

Comment: Recommend you update your gcc and include the version number in your question. See here: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/734

Comment: `xcode-select --install` solved it for me (which installs the most recent xcode cli tools), but my traceback said the xcode active developer path was missing a package